# Flask SocketIO issue with CORS

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

I have a Flask app where I am implementing SocketIO for the first time. My app is as follows:

app.py

```
app, api = create_app()

# JWT Configurations
jwt = JWTManager(app)

# Socket IO
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@socketio.on("livetweets")
def post_tweets(tweet):
    print("HIT")
    print(tweet)

...

# Start the app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app)
```

client.html

```
<html>
...

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/3.0.3/socket.io.min.js" integrity="sha512-uElffqRAo44n9cqo42itgRMY0L0zNZWEj3RGTQwyQsITiz4CB6rALOu1/S4O5iy/vFTMNs8gmTpDXB8mfQpjOg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: jQuery, Popper.js, and Bootstrap JS
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->

  <!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
  <script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){

      var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:5000')

      $('#tweets-live-start').on('click', function(){
        socket.emit('livetweets', 'start');
      });

    })
  </script>
```

However, when i click on the button to emit the "start" string, i see the request get sent but nothing is printing on my console. I checked the console on my browser and saw this message everytime:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NOVRekt' from origin 'http://localhost:5000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I looked this up online and tried several fixes where they suggest to use `var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:5000', { transport : ['websocket'] })` in the client, or even `socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")` in the flask app but it still doesn't work.

Can someone please help ?

Comment: Can someone help? I am really stuck on this

Comment: Try using a version 2.x of the JavaScript client. Version 3 is not currently supported in the Python Socket.IO (work is in progress for this).

Comment: It works with v2.x !
Thank you so much!